# Установка OpenFace на Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv

Здравствуйте.

Хочу установить OpenFace через Docker, система Windows 10.

https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/

Разобрался с Docker'ом, поставил, работает. Установил контейнер, но не могу понять, куда он установлен и как вообще его правильно поставить. Может я что-то некорректно понял. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Окно Kitematic'а приведено на скриншоте ниже:

[image: Окно Kitematic (Alpha)]

Answer (score 1):

Лично я использую Docker Quickstart Terminal, который идёт в поставке. Он автоматом подымет виртуальку линуксовую, нужно будет выкачать образ опенфейс и запустить его. Ну а дальше скармливаете свои фоточки предварительно подготовив их.

```
docker pull bamos/openface
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
```